# Matplotlib plotting same points on all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a loop that should create a bunch of subplots. the problem is that it seems to plot the same points on all the subplots, or rather that it carries over the points from the previous plot. so for example plot1 data is plotted on subplots 1,2,3. then plot 2 points are plotted on 2 and 3. Same happens when I do it manually without the loop.

```
number_of_subplots=len(list(chn.keys()))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(number_of_subplots, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})

i = 0
for x in chn.keys():
    ch = chn[x]
    p = ch[ch['kind'].str.contains('P')].sort_values(['strike'], inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    c = ch[ch['kind'].str.contains('C')].sort_values(['strike'], inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(c,p)
    axs[i].scatter(p['strike'], -p['volume'])
    axs[i].scatter(c['strike'], c['volume'])
    axs[i].set_ylabel(list(chn.keys())[i])

    i +=1


for ax in axs:
    ax.label_outer()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to run your code to figure out what's going on, but there are a lot of undefined variables

Comment: I don't think I can share the data frames here

Comment: well...make one up then.